# Onedrive API, set folder cover

Tags: onedrive

Is there any api that allows us to set the cover image of a folder programatically in OneDrive?  Couldn't find much about this in the [documentation](https://dev.onedrive.com/README.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that's not something that can be accomplished via the API at this time. Feel free to create (or upvote) a request on our [uservoice](https://onedrive.uservoice.com/forums/262982-onedrive/category/89523-developer) site and we'll look into it.